# How to get total of same key values using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, promise, es6-promise

I have an array of objects with two different values and I want total or these values according to the key value. How can I make it run properly? please help and thanks in advance.

```
var GetFinancial =  function() {
    var promises = [];
    fnancialObj = {};
    /* calculate total for Firsr*/
    let productAdsPaymentEventListArr = [{ "CurrencyAmount": "300" },{ "CurrencyAmount": "200"} ]
    let productAdsTotal = 0;
    productAdsPaymentEventListArr.forEach(function(productAdsPaymentEventListItem, index) {
        let valueType = 'productAdsPaymentTotal'
        promises.push(GetFinancialEventWithTotal(productAdsPaymentEventListItem.CurrencyAmount, productAdsTotal, fnancialObj, valueType))
    })
    /* calculate total of second*/
    let productAdsPaymentEventListArr2 = [{ "CurrencyAmount": "30"},{ "CurrencyAmount": "20"} ]
    let productAdsTotal2 = 0;
    productAdsPaymentEventListArr2.forEach(function(productAdsPaymentEventListItem2, index) {
        let valueType = 'productAdsPaymentTotal2'
        promises.push(GetFinancialEventWithTotal(productAdsPaymentEventListItem2.CurrencyAmount, productAdsTotal2, fnancialObj, valueType))
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(result) {
        console.log("product update or inserted successfully in all ", result)
        resolve(result)
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("err in update or inserted in all promise", err)
    })
}
```

Promice Defination is here:

```
var GetFinancialEventWithTotal = function(chargeComponent, totalCharge, fnancialObj, objectKey) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        totalCharge = totalCharge + parseFloat(chargeComponent);
        if (totalCharge) {
            fnancialObj[objectKey] = totalCharge;
            resolve(fnancialObj);
        } else {
            reject("There an Error")
        }
    })
}
```

I want output like this (addition of each value of each array according to key value) :

```
fnancialObj={
    productAdsPaymentTotal : 500,
    productAdsPaymentTotal2 :50,
}
```

Comment: But you're overriding the function `GetFinancialEventWithTotal`.  I don't understand!

Comment: Along with @Ele's observation, it doesn't look like the second `GetFinancialEventWithTotal` is doing anything asynchronous. Why are you wrapping it in a promise?

Comment: I'm not altogether sure you need _any_ promises based on that code. The `forEach`s are synchronous, as is the second `GetFinancialEventWithTotal` function.

Comment: This is a method and it will return promise. Promise definition is defined below.

Comment: @VishnuChauhan we see the Promise definition, but it's not clear why you are using a promise. Why not just return the value?

Comment: Because when all total value completed then I need further calculation with response defined in Promise.all. @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any Promises unless there is something asynchronous in your workflow. For you current problem you just need to add the amounts in an array of objects. This is what [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is for. Call `reduce()` on each array to get the sums and return an object with both results.

```js
var GetFinancial =  function() {

    /* calculate total for Firsr*/
    let productAdsPaymentEventListArr = [{ "CurrencyAmount": "300" },{ "CurrencyAmount": "200"} ]
    let productAdsTotal = productAdsPaymentEventListArr.reduce((total, current) => total + parseInt(current.CurrencyAmount), 0);

    /* calculate total of second*/
    let productAdsPaymentEventListArr2 = [{ "CurrencyAmount": "30"},{ "CurrencyAmount": "20"} ]
    let productAdsTotal2 = productAdsPaymentEventListArr2.reduce((total, current) => total + parseInt(current.CurrencyAmount), 0);

    return {
        productAdsPaymentTotal : productAdsTotal,
        productAdsPaymentTotal2 :productAdsTotal2,
    }
    
}
let financials = GetFinancial()
// do any further calculations you want with financials 
console.log(financials)
```

Comment: You can extract the reduce logic to a function for reuse. Something like `function sum(array, keyToSum)`; and then just call `sum(productAdsPaymentEventListArr, 'CurrencyAmount')`